# How to connect items to category in one to many relationship when insert data

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

i have 2 entities one customers and other is cases, the relationship is one to many one customer had many cases and the relation names toCustomers for cases entity and toCases for customers entity  so in my code i pass selected customer name by segue to the add cases UIViewController

```
var CustmerNameForAddNewCaseVar: Customers?
CustomerNameLbl.text = CustmerNameForAddNewCaseVar?.name
```

in the save button

```
let newCase : Cases!
    newCase = Cases(context:context)
    newCase.caseName = caseNameTextField.text
    newCase.toCustomers = CustmerNameForAddNewCaseVar?.name // here i got error ... Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'Customers?'
    do{
        AppDel.saveContext()
}catch{
        print(error)
    }
```

any help
thank you

Comment: It's very confusing to understand the model if all entities are named in plural form. Is `toCustomers` one case or many cases? Apart from that you have to assign the `Customer(s)` instance (not the name) to the relationship. By the way, that's exactly what the error message says.

Comment: toCustomers is the name of the relationship and Customers is the entity so i made the variable inherit from Customers to can read the name that inserted in it as u see in the code so when i recored new case i want assign it to the customer name so i do it like this i want to insert the customer name in the Relationship name so that many cases belong to one customer but it cant convert string which is customer name i got from  entity to the relationship name toCustomer which is type customer entity as i think

Comment: The relationship is always the **entity** not one of its attributes. Regarding naming: `let newCase : Cases` is a contradiction in terms, because the variable is singular but the entity is plural. Name the entities `Case` and `Customer` and the relationship `toCustomer` because it's supposed to be **one** `Customer`. However a *to-many* relationship name `cases`. because it's supposed to be **many** items of type `Case`. Also a declaration `[Cases]` is tautologous (double plural).

Comment: How I can convert the the customer name String to the customer entity type

Comment: *Convert* not at all. You need to get (fetch) the customer unless you already got a reference like `CustmerNameForAddNewCaseVar`. Another convention: Variable names (unlike class, struct and enum names) start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: i already have the name in the customerNameForAddCaseVar and i read in label, so as i told you i want put it in the toCustomer (which is the name of the relationship in case entity )so that i link the case to the specific customer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161914/discussion-between-mahmoud-and-vadian).

Comment: No, according to the code you have the **entity** instance in `CustmerNameForAddNewCaseVar`. Assign this.

Comment: what do u mean ??

Comment: You declared `CustmerNameForAddNewCaseVar` as  `Customers` so if the variable contains a value it's the instance of the **entity**, the object you are looking for.

Comment: anyway forget my code how i can connect customer to case ??? since i have already relationship

Comment: Why do you post the code although it's irrelevant? If you have the name fetch the corresponding object with a predicate from the database but it's preferable to keep the reference to the current customer in the (table data source) model instead of just the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use your example... you would alter your code to match this:

```swift
let newCase : Cases!
newCase = Cases(context:context)
newCase.caseName = caseNameTextField.text
newCase.toCustomers = CustmerNameForAddNewCaseVar
do {
    // Save Context
} catch {
    // Handle Error
}
```

Notice the line "newCase.toCustomers" has changed.

What others are suggesting in the comments to your question is to clear up the naming of your entities and variables to help clarify usage. An example would be:

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreData

class Customer: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var cases: Set<Case>?
}

class Case: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var customer: Customer?
    @NSManaged var name: String?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var customer: Customer?
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext?

    @IBOutlet weak var caseName: UITextField?

    @IBAction func didTapSave(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let context = self.context else {
            return
        }

        guard let customer = self.customer else {
            return
        }

        let newCase = Case(context: context)
        newCase.name = caseName?.text
        newCase.customer = customer

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Handle Error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer i already find it out should only use newCase.toCustomers = CustmerNameForAddNewCaseVar without .name and the core data do the all for me, but i see you also give what i find it out, so thank you very much for your answer and for your time to read and answer my question :-)